# Find node and insert

Tags: java

I'm trying to search for a node in Word Frequency List and return in case it's there, otherwise, return null. but my method keep return only null and i couldn't figure out why! can someone tell me if i miss something?

```
private class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    private E key;
    private int count;
    private Node next;

    Node(E item){
        key = item;
        count = 1;
        next = null;
    }
}

private Node find(Node n){
    Node current = first;

    while(current!=null && !current.equals(n)){
        current=current.next;
    }

    if(current!=null)
        return current;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more code. E.g. where is `first` coming from? How are you building/initializing your linked list of `Node`s? My gut feeling is that when building your list, you might not be setting `next`, so traversal isn't actually happening. Have you tried using the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

As @pyepye said in the comments, you're setting `Node next` to be `null` for every node you create. From wherever you're calling the `find` method, you should have created a linked list beforehand, and making sure the next nodes are pointing to the actual next node.

The reason your program is returning `null` is probably because of this error.

EDIT:

Another possible error is that you're using the `equals` method. The `Comparable` interface contains the `compareTo` method, not the `equals` method. Perhaps the `equals` method in your `Node` class doesn't function properly, and therefore your `find` method isn't actually finding any correct node.

So use

```
while (current!=null && current.compareTo(n)!=0)
```